# How to select an option from dropdown list by matching text pattern using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to select an option from a dropdown list by matching only some part of visible text, since the whole text is not going to always be the same. Can anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this but here's how you would do it in C#, you should be able to transpose this quite easily into Java code. Two ways I can think of:

**1)**

```
string selBoxID = "id of select box";
string partialText = "option text to match";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='" + selBoxID + "']/option[contains(text(), '" + partialText + "')]")).Click();
```

OR

**2)**

```
SelectElement elSel = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("id of select box")));
IList<IWebElement> opts = elSel.Options;
foreach (IWebElement elOpt in opts)
{
    if(elOpt.Text.Contains("partial text to look for"){
        elOpt.Click();
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: +1, for reference though, the Java equivalent is the `Select` class: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java

Answer (score 1):

C# with LINQ

```
var menuOptions = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement({LocatorForMenu})).Options;
var requiredOption = menuOptions.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Text.Contains(partialTextToMatch));
if (requiredOption == null)
    throw new Exception("Wasn't able to select menu item: " + partialTextToMatch);
requiredOption.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work?

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MyIdOrOtherSelector"))).selectByVisibleText("Something");
```

Though I'm not sure if that will allow partial text.
There is also

```
selectByValue(value)
selectByIndex(index)
```

If they are any use

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java code for this

```
    WebElement dropdown = driverObj.findElement(By.id(id));
    dropdown.click();

    List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for(WebElement option : options){
        String optTxt = option.getText();
        if(optTxt.contains(partialText)){
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below command. Let me know if it is working.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id of the dropdown")).sendkeys("part of visible text");
driver.findElement(By.id("id of the dropdown")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. The problem with this one is, the text pattern I'm trying to find here should be the starting text. Also It's not releasing the focus from the element.