# Is it possible to select an element (drop-down value) using which contains?

Tags: c#, selenium

Is it possible to select an element (drop-down value) using which contains?

My drop-down value is of 25 characters, as of now i'm using

`myelement.SelectByText(mytext);` **// *Here i'm passing full text of the drop-down*** value.

Wondering is it possible to select by passing partial value of the text?

Please let me know. (*Possible C# answers would be helpful*)

Comment: Here is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455783/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-list-by-matching-text-pattern-using-seleni

Comment: You can try to find element by index which will be fast.

Comment: Thank you helping hands, this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455783/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-list-by-matching-text-pattern-using-seleni)
provided the solution.. 
using .SelectByValue(partial text);
this working fine.

thank you

Comment: Great...Cheers......:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code it should work

```
WebElement web = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"));
List<WebElement> lst2 = web.findElements(By
        .xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'<yourText>')]"));
    for (WebElement option : lst2) {
    if (!option.isSelected()) {
        option.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rupesh, but this will cause a performance issue bcz my dropdown list contains 30 + entries, if i loop each index(value) and verify with my selectionstring then selecting it..

SelectElement MyDropdown=new SelectElement(WebElement);
MyDropdown.SelectByText(myfulltext of the value);
// instead of passing full text, is there a way to pass partial text to select the dropdown value?